# Google analytic GA4 page views without gmail account

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-analytics, google-oauth

I now that GA4 is using  OAuth 2.0 now.
Is there a way to get page views without permission through email popup?

Many users is using my app and I want to give them access to download page views of their specific requests.
They don't have gmail accounts so how I can authorize them by OAuth 2.0?
(It's node app)